# Is there a way for bulk insert or update of records using Hibernate

Tags: java, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert or update few records in oracle using hibernate. I am having around 2000 entities (records), which i am currently inserting/updating one by one sequentially. this is taking a lot of time for me to complete as hibernate internally selecting and then doing insert/update. I want to know is there a way that i can do bulk insert/update in hibernate. If yes, please do let me know how i can do that. and also do let me know are there any bottlenecks in doing bulk operations.
below is the way how i am doing save/update using hibernate

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory session;

private Session getSession() {
    return session.getCurrentSession();
}

@Override
public Integer saveOrUpdateTest(Test test) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(test);
    return test.getTestId();
}
```

Below is the entity class that i am using.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Test")
public class Test implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8844487972789619819L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="TEST_ID")
private Integer testid;

@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Integer employee_ID;

@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_SUB_ID")
private Integer employee_Sub_ID;

public Integer getTestId() {
    return testid;
}

public void setTestId(Integer testid) {
    this.testid = testid;
}

public Integer getEmployeeId() {
    return employee_ID;
}

public void setEmployeeId(Integer employee_ID) {
    this.employee_ID = employee_ID;
}

public Integer getEmployeeSubId() {
    return employee_Sub_ID;
}

public void setCapEmployeeSubId(Integer employee_Sub_ID) {
    this.employee_Sub_ID = employee_Sub_ID;
}

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349464/bulk-insert-or-update-with-hibernate Go through this Link and For update also use hql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349464/bulk-insert-or-update-with-hibernate)!
This will work for your Scenario.